# Use dax variable inside filter

Tags: variables, filter, powerbi, dax

Edit: looks like this is the wrong approach and won't work.

I am trying to filter a table based on how another table is already filtered by building a variable and using it in the filter, but I seem to be doing something wrong. Here is a sample of the data I am working with:

[image: image of data sample]

I have built a filtered version of the table using the following code:

```
Filtered_ALL_METRICS_patient_pivot = 
    VAR _ConditionsList = 
        IF ( CONCATENATEX(DISTINCT(VALUES(AllPatients[CAD])), [CAD], " ") = "1", ", 'CAD'", "" )
        & IF ( CONCATENATEX(DISTINCT(VALUES(AllPatients[CHF])), [CHF], " ") = "1", ", 'CHF'", "" )
        & IF ( CONCATENATEX(DISTINCT(VALUES(AllPatients[COPDAsthma])), [COPDAsthma], " ") = "1", ", 'COPDAsthma'", "" )
        & IF ( CONCATENATEX(DISTINCT(VALUES(AllPatients[Diabetes])), [Diabetes], " ") = "1", ", 'Diabetes'", "" )
        & IF ( CONCATENATEX(DISTINCT(VALUES(AllPatients[HLD])), [HLD], " ") = "1", ", 'HLD'", "" )
        & IF ( CONCATENATEX(DISTINCT(VALUES(AllPatients[HTN])), [HTN], " ") = "1", ", 'HTN'", "" )
    VAR _FilterList =  IF ( LEN ( _ConditionsList ) = 0, "'CAD', 'CHF', 'COPDAsthma', 'Diabetes', 'HLD', 'HTN'", RIGHT ( _ConditionsList, LEN ( _ConditionsList ) - 2 ) )
    RETURN 
    FILTER(ALL_METRICS_patient_pivot, ALL_METRICS_patient_pivot[metric] IN {_FilterList})
```

But no matter what I have selected, the filtered table is empty. What am I doing wrong?

I currently do not have relationships set up between the filtered table and any other table. I have tried connecting it to several other tables that are being filtered correctly, but this did not give me any rows in the filtered table.

I have confirmed that _FilterList is outputting what I intend (e.g., `'CAD', 'CHF', 'COPDAsthma', 'Diabetes', 'HLD', 'HTN'` if everything or nothing is selected, and `'CHF', 'Diabetes'` if just those two conditions are selected) by creating a metric that is the same but returns _FilterList instead. I included an x in front of the variable names in the metric to avoid any potential scoping issues.

Any help is appreciated, as dax is not my strong point!

Comment: Calculated Tables and Calculated Columns are calculated one time during dataset refresh - that is to say, they are not dynamic and will not interact with slicers/filters at 'run/view time'. If you are looking to filter one table based on another without interaction then I would recommend doing so via PowerQuery. If you are wanting to show rows based on what is sliced/filtered in the report, and wanting it to change, then you cannot use Calculated Table - instead you will need to use Measures. Please confirm what it is you are wanting.

Comment: @SamNseir Yes, I am trying to filter one table based on another without interaction. I'm not very familiar with PowerQuery, so I'll look into that. Thank you!